# Alternatives to WebResponse/HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a simple program to return the status code from a website. Currently using the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes. However the way they work just seems horrible to me, the status code is only returned if its 200/OK, and all other codes give a webexception.

While I can read the response from the exception and get the status code I was wondering if there are any other alternatives that don't cause exceptions. As I understand exceptions are costly and should be reserved for rare occasions when there are serious problems. Not that it matters for my application but I'd rather avoid exceptions unless absolutely necessary.

So are there any other options?

Edit:

Here's some code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.randomsite.com");
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine("Status: " + response.StatusCode);

                response.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) ex.Response;
                if (httpResponse != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Status: " + httpResponse.StatusCode);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where's your code?  What exceptions?

Comment: `As I understand exceptions are costly and should be reserved for rare occasions when there are serious problems.` Where exactly did you get this "understanding"?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Pretty much everywhere you look where exceptions and cost are discussed.

Answer (score 3):

While exceptions are costly, they are many powers of ten less costly than a web request. So just wrap HttpWebResponse to give you back the status code and forget about the cost.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to write a simple program to return the status code from a website.

The status of what?  Do you just want to figure out if the application is running?  `HttpWebResponse.StatusCode` returns the status of the response, not the status of the site.  If you return anything other than 200, you are saying the request was invalid or could not be processed for some reason.

I agree with Eugen that you shouldn't be concerned about performance in this case, but I have a feeling you are also barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I'm just making a request to a website url and getting the response and checking the status code of the response to see if the website is ok, 404, redirect or whatever. Thought this was clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  Your comment and added code example makes your intent clear.  If I have an alternative method not involving `WebException`, I'll post it in another answer.